# Share an object for Web User Controls (Asp.NET, C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm developing a Cms.
There are some web user controls;

TopMenu.asx
SubMenu.ascx
FooterMenu.ascx

I do not want them to go Database for Site Map several time.
1 query is enough.

Is there a way to do this without using an Session Object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Caching is the usual suspect for such things. Integrated into the view mark up you could research the PageOutputCache .

Andrew

Comment: In fact, I am looking for an object sharing with Business Layer and web User Controls. When page load method run, the object will be filled. Than the controls will user the object.